# Alguna forma de evitar los numeros que crea random? JS

Tags: javascript, phaser3

Soy nuevo en esto y estoy haciendo un juego pequeno juego en JS, y ahora lo que me esta volviendo loco es generar los enemigos de una manera en la que no aparezcan tan pegados uno de los otros, mas "natural" digamoslo asi, para evitar esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para generarlos lo que yo hago es algo simple:

```
resetShip(enemy_spaceship) {
    enemy_spaceship.y = 0;
    enemy_spaceship.x = Phaser.Math.Between(10,globalThis.config.width);
}
```

el problema con esto es que supongamos que a un sprite le toco 452 en X y a otro le toco 462 en X, esos 13px de diferencia son muy pocos para que esten lo suficientemente alejado uno de los otros, causando que aparezcan pegados o muy cerca, lo que estoy pensando es por ejemplo que aparezcan con una diferencia de pixeles de distancia, pero de verdad no se me ocurre ninguna manera, pensaba en que si un sprite salio en la posicion 420 y otro sale en 450, volver a asignarle una nueva posicion que no este en el rango de los 400 a 499, pero como dije anteriormente, de verdad no se como implementarlo :(

Answer (score 2):

Divide el rango entre el tamaño del enemigo (o el margen que quieras dejar entre ellos) , elige un numero aleatorio entre este nuevo rango, y el resultado lo vuelves a multiplicar por ese mismo margen. Luego tendrás el problema de que dos enemigos ocupen el mismo espacio, para eso podrías guardar los valores en un array e ir comprobando si ya fué seleccionado.

```js
    var enemigos = 10 ;

    var enemigoWidth = 64;
    var enemigoHeight = 64;
    var pantallaWidth = 600;
    var pantallaHeight = 800;

    var rangoWidth = pantallaWidth / enemigoWidth;
    var rangoHeight = pantallaHeight / enemigoHeight;

    var enemigo=[];

    for (let i=0 ; i<enemigos ; i++){
      let x,y;
      do {
        x = Math.floor(Math.random()*rangoWidth)*enemigoWidth;
        y = Math.floor(Math.random()*rangoHeight)*enemigoHeight;
      } while (enemigo.find(function(o){
        return o[0]==x && o[1]==y;
     }));
      enemigo.push([x,y]);
      console.log(x,y);
    }
```

¡OJO! La solución para no repetir posiciones es mala, se corre el peligro de tardar en encontrar una posición libre, o incluso de no salir del bucle si no queda ninguna, solo habría que usarla con pocos enemigos, he usado esta por ser simple.

EDIT:
Una solución para no repetir posiciones sin peligro seria crear una matriz con todas las posibles posiciones, e ir sacando posiciones aleatoriamente hasta terminar los enemigos, o se terminen las posiciones.
Claro que esta solución solo sirve si la lista de posibles posiciones no es demasiado larga.

```js
    var enemigos = 1000 ; // realmente solo hay 108 posiciones disponibles, así que pondrá como máximo 108 enemigos.

    var enemigoWidth = 64;
    var enemigoHeight = 64;
    var pantallaWidth = 600;
    var pantallaHeight = 800;

    var rangoWidth = Math.floor(pantallaWidth / enemigoWidth);
    var rangoHeight = Math.floor(pantallaHeight / enemigoHeight);

    var enemigo=[];

    var posiciones=[];
    for (let i=0 ; i<rangoWidth*rangoHeight; i++){
        posiciones[i]=i;
    }
        for (let i=0 ; i<enemigos && posiciones.length>0 ; i++){
        let p = Math.floor(Math.random()*posiciones.length);
        let n = posiciones[p];
        posiciones.splice(p,1);
        let x = Math.floor(n/rangoHeight);
        let y = n%rangoHeight;
      enemigo.push([x*enemigoWidth,y*enemigoHeight]);
      console.log(x*enemigoHeight,y*enemigoHeight);
    }
  console.log(enemigo.length+" enemigos");
```